# How to order results with findBy() in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am using the `findBy()` method on a Doctrine repository:

```
$entities = $repository->findBy(array('type'=> 'C12'));
```

How can I order the results?

Answer (score 354, accepted):

The second parameter of `findBy` is for ORDER.

```
$ens = $em->getRepository('AcmeBinBundle:Marks')
          ->findBy(
             array('type'=> 'C12'), 
             array('id' => 'ASC')
           );
```

Comment: Apparently the API documentation on the doctrine website doesn't match the actual source code. https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.4/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php shows that you are correct.

Comment: Can I set mutliple order by ?

Comment: A little late finding this question, but for anyone else wondering about this, yes you can add multiple "order by", just add more elements in that second parameter array and define the field names 'ASC' or 'DESC'.  IE: `array('priority'=>'ASC','id'=>'ASC')`.

Comment: What if AcmeBinBundle:Marks is related ManyToOne with "product" and we want to order by a field in product object? Is this posible?

Comment: @RodolVelasco `findBy` is used for basic query scene, for more complicate scene, use query instead. like `$qb = $em->getRepository('AcmeBinBundle:Marks')->createQueryBuilder('m')->...`.

Comment: is this also valid for findOneBy?

Answer (score 31):

```
$ens = $em->getRepository('AcmeBinBundle:Marks')
              ->findBy(
                 array(), 
                 array('id' => 'ASC')
               );
```

Answer (score 14):

```
$cRepo = $em->getRepository('KaleLocationBundle:Country');

// Leave the first array blank
$countries = $cRepo->findBy(array(), array('name'=>'asc'));
```