# Order by an specific related field with doctrine2 findoneby functionality

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to find one data with findbyone option but by accesing the related object. Next you'll find the two of the entities Im using.

**Caja.php**

```
<?php

namespace PD\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use APY\DataGridBundle\Grid\Mapping as GRID;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="caja") 
 * 
 */
class Caja
{
    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Id 
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer") 
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @GRID\Column(title="Número carton")
    */
    protected $numero_carton;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100) */
    protected $contiene_libreta_limite_inferior;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100) */
    protected $contiene_libreta_limite_superior;

    /** 
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100) 
    * @GRID\Column(title="Libretas omitidas")
    */
    protected $omite_libreta;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100) 
     * @GRID\Column(title="Total libretas")
     */
    protected $total_libretas;

    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PD\AppBundle\Entity\Juego") 
     *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="juego_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * */
    protected $juego;

    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario") **/
    protected $usuario;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @GRID\Column(title="Fecha creación")
     */
    protected $fecha_creacion;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="estado", type="string", length=50)
     * @GRID\Column(title="Estado")
     */
    protected $estado;
    /* 
     * 1 = CREADO
     * 2 = ASIGNADO_A_SUPERVISOR
     * 3 = FINALIZADO_CON_EXITO
     * 4 = FINALIZADO_CON_OBSERVACIONES
     * 5 = DESHABILITADO
     * 
     */

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PD\AppBundle\Entity\Libreta", mappedBy="caja", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
     */
    protected $libretas;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fecha_creacion = new \DateTime();
        $this->libretas = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set numero_carton
     *
     * @param string $numeroCarton
     * @return Caja
     */
    public function setNumeroCarton($numeroCarton)
    {
        $this->numero_carton = $numeroCarton;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get numero_carton
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNumeroCarton()
    {
        return $this->numero_carton;
    }

    /**
     * Set contiene_libreta_limite_inferior
     *
     * @param string $contieneLibretaLimiteInferior
     * @return Caja
     */
    public function setContieneLibretaLimiteInferior($contieneLibretaLimiteInferior)
    {
        $this->contiene_libreta_limite_inferior = $contieneLibretaLimiteInferior;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get contiene_libreta_limite_inferior
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContieneLibretaLimiteInferior()
    {
        return $this->contiene_libreta_limite_inferior;
    }

    /**
     * Set contiene_libreta_limite_superior
     *
     * @param string $contieneLibretaLimiteSuperior
     * @return Caja
     */
    public function setContieneLibretaLimiteSuperior($contieneLibretaLimiteSuperior)
    {
        $this->contiene_libreta_limite_superior = $contieneLibretaLimiteSuperior;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get contiene_libreta_limite_superior
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContieneLibretaLimiteSuperior()
    {
        return $this->contiene_libreta_limite_superior;
    }

    /**
     * Set omite_libreta
     *
     * @param string $omiteLibreta
     * @return Caja
     */
    public function setOmiteLibreta($omiteLibreta)
    {
        $this->omite_libreta = $omiteLibreta;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get omite_libreta
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getOmiteLibreta()
    {
        return $this->omite_libreta;
    }

    /**
     * Set total_libretas
     *
     * @param string $totalLibretas
     * @return Caja
     */
    public function setTotalLibretas($totalLibretas)
    {
        $this->total_libretas = $totalLibretas;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total_libretas
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTotalLibretas()
    {
        return $this->total_libretas;
    }

    /**
     * Set juego
     *
     * @param \PD\AppBundle\Entity\Juego $juego
     * @return Caja
     */
    public function setJuego(\PD\AppBundle\Entity\Juego $juego)
    {
        $this->juego = $juego;
    }

    /**
     * Get juego
     *
     * @return \PD\AppBundle\Entity\Juego 
     */
    public function getJuego()
    {
        return $this->juego;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getNumeroCarton();
    }

    /**
     * Set usuario
     *
     * @param \PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario $usuario
     * @return Caja
     */
    public function setUsuario(\PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario $usuario)
    {
        $this->usuario = $usuario;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get usuario
     *
     * @return \PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario 
     */
    public function getUsuario()
    {
        return $this->usuario;
    }

    /**
     * Set fecha_creacion
     *
     * @param \DateTime $fechaCreacion
     * @return Caja
     */
    public function setFechaCreacion($fechaCreacion)
    {
        $this->fecha_creacion = $fechaCreacion;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fecha_creacion
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getFechaCreacion()
    {
        return $this->fecha_creacion;
    }

    /**
     * Set estado
     *
     * @param string $estado
     * @return Caja
     */
    public function setEstado($estado)
    {
        $this->estado = $estado;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get estado
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEstado()
    {
        return $this->estado;
    }

    /**
     * Add libretas
     *
     * @param \PD\AppBundle\Entity\Libreta $libretas
     * @return Caja
     */
    public function addLibreta(\PD\AppBundle\Entity\Libreta $libretas)
    {
        //$this->libretas[] = $libretas;
        //return $this;

        $libretas->setCaja($this);
        $this->libretas->add($libretas);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove libretas
     *
     * @param \PD\AppBundle\Entity\Libreta $libretas
     */
    public function removeLibreta(\PD\AppBundle\Entity\Libreta $libretas)
    {
        $this->libretas->removeElement($libretas);
    }

    /**
     * Get libretas
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getLibretas()
    {
        return $this->libretas;
    }
}
```

**Libreta.php**

```
<?php

namespace PD\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use APY\DataGridBundle\Grid\Mapping as GRID;

/**
 * Libreta
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Libreta
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** 
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PD\AppBundle\Entity\Caja", inversedBy="libretas") 
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="caja_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
      * @Assert\Type(type="PD\AppBundle\Entity\Caja")
      * @GRID\Column(field="caja.juego.nombre", title="Juego")
      * @GRID\Column(field="caja.numero_carton", title="Caja")
     */
    protected $caja;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="correlativo", type="string", length=10)
     * @GRID\Column(title="Correlativo")
     */
    private $correlativo;

    /** 
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario") 
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="vendedor_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
      * @Assert\Type(type="PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario")
      * @GRID\Column(field="vendedor.nombre", title="Nombre vendedor")
      * @GRID\Column(field="vendedor.apellidos", title="Apellidos vendedor")
     */
    protected $vendedor;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="precio_al_vendedor", type="decimal", scale=2) */
    protected $precio_al_vendedor;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="precio_acumulado", type="decimal", scale=2) 
      * @GRID\Column(title="Precio acumulado")
    */
    protected $precio_acumulado;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="premio_acumulado", type="decimal", scale=2) 
      * @GRID\Column(title="Premio acumulado")
    */
    protected $premio_acumulado;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true) 
     */
    protected $fecha_asignacion_vendedor;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true) 
     */
    protected $fecha_estado_final;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PD\AppBundle\Entity\Ticket", mappedBy="libreta", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $tickets;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set correlativo
     *
     * @param string $correlativo
     * @return Libreta
     */
    public function setCorrelativo($correlativo)
    {
        $this->correlativo = $correlativo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get correlativo
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCorrelativo()
    {
        return $this->correlativo;
    }

    /**
     * Set precio_al_vendedor
     *
     * @param string $precioAlVendedor
     * @return Libreta
     */
    public function setPrecioAlVendedor($precioAlVendedor)
    {
        $this->precio_al_vendedor = $precioAlVendedor;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get precio_al_vendedor
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPrecioAlVendedor()
    {
        return $this->precio_al_vendedor;
    }

    /**
     * Set precio_acumulado
     *
     * @param string $precioAcumulado
     * @return Libreta
     */
    public function setPrecioAcumulado($precioAcumulado)
    {
        $this->precio_acumulado = $precioAcumulado;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get precio_acumulado
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPrecioAcumulado()
    {
        return $this->precio_acumulado;
    }

    /**
     * Set fecha_asignacion_vendedor
     *
     * @param \DateTime $fechaAsignacionVendedor
     * @return Libreta
     */
    public function setFechaAsignacionVendedor($fechaAsignacionVendedor)
    {
        $this->fecha_asignacion_vendedor = $fechaAsignacionVendedor;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fecha_asignacion_vendedor
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getFechaAsignacionVendedor()
    {
        return $this->fecha_asignacion_vendedor;
    }

    /**
     * Set fecha_estado_final
     *
     * @param \DateTime $fechaEstadoFinal
     * @return Libreta
     */
    public function setFechaEstadoFinal($fechaEstadoFinal)
    {
        $this->fecha_estado_final = $fechaEstadoFinal;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fecha_estado_final
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getFechaEstadoFinal()
    {
        return $this->fecha_estado_final;
    }

    /**
     * Set vendedor
     *
     * @param \PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario $vendedor
     * @return Libreta
     */
    public function setVendedor(\PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario $vendedor = null)
    {
        $this->vendedor = $vendedor;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get vendedor
     *
     * @return \PD\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario 
     */
    public function getVendedor()
    {
        return $this->vendedor;
    }

    /**
     * Set caja
     *
     * @param \PD\AppBundle\Entity\Caja $caja
     * @return Libreta
     */
    public function setCaja(\PD\AppBundle\Entity\Caja $caja = null)
    {
        $this->caja = $caja;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get caja
     *
     * @return \PD\AppBundle\Entity\Caja 
     */
    public function getCaja()
    {
        return $this->caja;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tickets = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        //$this->caja = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add tickets
     *
     * @param \PD\AppBundle\Entity\Ticket $tickets
     * @return Libreta
     */
    public function addTicket(\PD\AppBundle\Entity\Ticket $tickets)
    {
        //$this->tickets[] = $tickets;

        $tickets->setLibreta($this);

        $this->tickets->add($tickets);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove tickets
     *
     * @param \PD\AppBundle\Entity\Ticket $tickets
     */
    public function removeTicket(\PD\AppBundle\Entity\Ticket $tickets)
    {
        $this->tickets->removeElement($tickets);
    }

    /**
     * Get tickets
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getTickets()
    {
        return $this->tickets;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->correlativo;
    }

    /**
     * Set premio_acumulado
     *
     * @param string $premioAcumulado
     * @return Libreta
     */
    public function setPremioAcumulado($premioAcumulado)
    {
        $this->premio_acumulado = $premioAcumulado;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get premio_acumulado
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPremioAcumulado()
    {
        return $this->premio_acumulado;
    }
}
```

And what I would like to do is to find one next row ordered by field "fecha_creacion". This is what I have that get the next row but ordered by caja ID

```
$libreta_siguiente = $this->getDoctrine()
                             ->getRepository('PDBundle:Libreta')
                             ->findOneBy(array('vendedor' => NULL), array('caja' => 'DESC'));
```

But what I want to know if I can do something like "array('caja.fecha_creacion' => 'DESC'));". Until now, this part of the code isn't recognizing the "fecha_creacion" field

```
$libreta_siguiente = $this->getDoctrine()
                             ->getRepository('PDBundle:Libreta')
                             ->findOneBy(array('vendedor' => NULL), array('caja.fecha_creacion' => 'DESC'));
```

Comment: Probably it's what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048452/how-to-use-orderby-in-doctrine-with-findby-function-in-symfony2

Comment: Thanks but that you mentioned brings more than one result and I would like to find the next unique more recent information. Is this possible with FindOneBy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html), you can't pass a second parameter to the `findOnyBy` function.

But you can try to cheat by using the `findBy` methods and the position of this array :

```
$libreta_siguiente = $this->getDoctrine()
                         ->getRepository('PDBundle:Libreta')
                         ->findNextLibreta(NULL, $actualPosicion);

...
```

And in your repository :

```
public function findNextLibreta($vendedor, $posicion) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l');
    $qb->leftJoin(l.caja, 'c')
       ->where('l.vendedor = :vendedor')
       ->setParameter(':type', $type)
       ->orderBy('c.fecha_creacion', 'DESC');
    $results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    return $results[$posicion];
}
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't work. I got "Unrecognized field: caja.fecha_creacion".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JulienBourdic I changed a little his proposal but him basically gave me the answer. The code is:

```
$posicion = 0;
                $libreta_siguiente = $this->getDoctrine()
                         ->getRepository('PDBundle:Libreta')
                         ->findByNextLibreta($posicion);
```

Then in LibretaRepository.php

```
public function findByNextLibreta($posicion) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l');
        $qb->leftJoin('l.caja', 'c')
           ->where('l.vendedor is NULL')
           ->orderBy('c.fecha_creacion', 'DESC');
        $results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
        return $results[$posicion];
    }
```

It differs a little cuz didn't know how to pass the NULL value Julien was proposing so I used **l.vendedor is NULL** burned in the code.